# Long section names in beamer document: headers and section transitions

Tags: beamer, titles

I have long titles for mi sections in a `beamer` document and  they take a long size of the header where I have the index. I have named them with a short name and a long name.
In both the header and the transition of each chapter they apperar the short titles, however I want the short version in the header and the long version for the transition of each section.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
    % Transition with the name of the section
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------%



% For colors
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
% For columns
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{biblatex}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%--------------------------%
% To add enumeration index
%--------------------------%
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber 
}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% PREAMBLE: dots for each slide of a section
    %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{remreset}% tiny package containing just the \@removefromreset command
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}

% Images vertically aligned
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small} %Reduce the size of Authors

\title{\large\textbf{Title}}

\vspace{5cm}

\author{\textbf{Author 1}}
\vspace{0.15cm}


\date{November 19, 2018}


\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla} 

%% GENERAR PORTADA %%

\frame[plain]{\titlepage}




%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------%


\section[Section 1]{This is the long title for the Section 1}

\section[Section 2]{This is the long title for the Section 2}

\section[Section 3]{This is the long title for the Section 3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\insertsectionhead` will give you the section name as in the header. To get the long version, use `\insertsection`

Some comments about your code:

- It makes no sense to use use `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` if you later overwrite it with `\setbeamercovered{dynamic}`
- unless you specify otherwise, beamer frames are vertically centred by default, so you can remove the `\vfill`s from your section page
- `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` is already loaded by beamer
- `\usepackage{multicol}` is unnecessary beamer has its own column mechanism
- `\usepackage{remreset}` is obsolet
- don't mess with formatting instructions in arguments of macros like author or title, use `\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large, series=\bfseries}` and  `\setbeamerfont{author}{series=\bfseries}` instead
- manual spacing instructions like `\vspace{5cm}` don't make sense in the preamble

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},10pt]{beamer}


%\setbeamercovered{transparent} useless as it is overwritten by dynamic
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}

% Transition with the name of the section
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  %\vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsection\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  %\vfill
  \end{frame}
}

%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % already laoded by beamer
%\usepackage{multicol} % unnecessary
%\usepackage{remreset} % obsolet

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large, series=\bfseries}
\title{Title}

%\vspace{5cm} %Makes no sense in preamble

\setbeamerfont{author}{series=\bfseries}
\author{Author 1}

%\vspace{0.15cm} %Makes no sense in preamble

\begin{document}

\section[Section 1]{This is the long title for the Section 1}
\section[Section 2]{This is the long title for the Section 2}
\section[Section 3]{This is the long title for the Section 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! So, the unique change was to delete the `head` in `\usebeamerfont{title}\insertsection\par`

Comment: @R18 Quite some more changes, I made a list